# How to add "Service State" service application?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration, service-applications

I am using SP2013 onpremise.

I logged in with farm account in CA. I go to the wizard and check if "State Service" is checked. I check it and finished the wizard. After the wizard was finished I see this:

[image]

I go to the service applications. I dont see there a "State Service service application". I try to add a new service application, but I dont see there "State Service" listed. So I cannot add a new "State Service service application".

[image]

I went to the service applications associations. Here I see all service applications are checked. But there is no "State Service service application".

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: In addition to the answer below: If you did not run the configuration wizard to create all the service applications, you have to create it by yourself using powershell. If you are unsure of what services you got you can always use the get-spserviceapplication cmdlt to see all the services in your farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State Service Service Application is indeed not available through UI.

Try the following commands:

```
$serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name “State Service Application”
New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name “SharePoint_Service_State” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp
New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name “State Service Application Proxy” -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```

Source: http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/02/14/create-a-new-state-service-service-application-using-powershell/